# D3.js charts placed in a bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am trying to make a slideshow of D3 charts using the bootstrap carousel. I have my charts created in separate javascript files and I put the location of the files in the source for the carousel items, but I am getting no output. There is also no error messages shown on the console.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active" id="chartArea1">
          <img src="scripts/nelsonAlanModel.js">
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="chartArea2">
          <img src="scripts/nelsonAlanModel_2.js">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="scripts/coxPropHazModel.js" >
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought if I gave the respective carousel items an id for which D3 to draw the charts, that should work. How can I go about making the charts show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your charts you can define where to place it on you DOM, being an `svg` item for the most part (*the same concept applies for other ways such as adding `div`'s for a bar chart or using a canvas*). So add your JavaScript inside `<script>` after your DOM items:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" id="chartArea1">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
...
<script src="scripts/nelsonAlanModel.js"></script>
```

Inside say `nelsonAlanModel.js` append an `svg` to the element with the id `chartArea1` by doing:

```
d3.select("#chartArea1").append("svg")
    ...
```

And so on for the rest of the items.

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/g03xvfvu/) using some basic charts of a circle and a box inside a boostrap carousel.

Comment: Silly me, I didn't notice that the scripts were place in an `img` tag. Its working now. Thanks for the answer tho